# Not receiving good speed on a particular Wi-Fi network

Tags: wireless-networking, internet

I am using a shared Wi-Fi connection. I am the only person who is not getting good Internet speed. Other devices receive great speed.

My system setup is:

- **OS:** Windows Vista Home Basic
- **Laptop:** [Dell Inspiron 1545](http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-inspiron-1545-15-6-p-t4200-vista-home-premium-3-gb-ram-250-gb-hdd-series/specs/)
- **Router:** [Sagecom Fast 5250 Home Hub 2000](http://support.bell.ca/Internet/Connection-help/Managing-Wi-Fi-networks-on-your-Home-Hub-2000-modem#displayStep)

When I connect to other networks, I get good speed. What could be wrong? Here are the results of tests on [Speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net):

My roommate is getting a speed of:

- **download:** 24.5 mbps
- **upload:** 7.32 mbps

My laptop is giving:

- **download:** 0.75 mbps
- **upload:** 0.21 mbps

**EDIT:**

**Router Security Type:**

- No Security
- WEP 64 bits
- WEP 128 bits
- WPA-PSK (TKIP)
- WPA2-PSK (AES)
- WPA/WPA2-PSK (TKIP/AES)

I tried with WPA/WPA2-PSK and WPA2-PSK and failed. I am still receiving poor speed.

Comment: @jake edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you tried updating the notebooks wireless driver (start with this if You haven't done it before) and that did not resolve the problem here is my experience:

I met similar cases where the encryption was the main problem. The notebook was an older model and could not handle the routers AES right.

It caused slowness and connection drops. Try to enter the routers wireless menu and if You have the option, set the encryption type to TKIP or WPA personal (not WPA2)

You can read more about TKIP and AES [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access)

Comment: edited my question.

Comment: @Touchstone And did You try with •WPA-PSK (TKIP) and •No Security? Is the QoS enabled on the router?